# Why is my button not re directing the user to another page?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using the framework bootstrap 4 and I was wondering why is my button not re directing the user to another page?

```
<button type="button" a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Contact Us <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></button>
```

Comment: Read up [HTML anchor vs button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are not links (and don't have a boolean `a` attribute).

If you want a link, use a link:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Contact Us <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
```